¿Como solucionar el error 'CORS Policy' con javascript y python?
Hola cree una api con python pero estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de consumirla cuando la tengo expuesta en un API gateway de AWS, la forma en como tengo creada es la siguiente:
archivo app.py
import awsgi
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config.update(JSON_AS_ASCII=False)

with app.app_context():
   import services.routes

def handler(event, context):
   print('event', event)
   output = awsgi.response(app, event, context)
   print('output', output)
   return output 

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)

este es mi archivo de routes.py
from services.memoramaS import MemoramaS
from services.wordSearchS import WordSearchS
from services.loginS import LoginS
from flask import jsonify, request, current_app as app
from flask_cors import cross_origin
import base64
import os

app.secret_key = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

@app.route('/admin-juegos/get-memoramas', methods = ['GET'])
@cross_origin()
def getMemoramas():
   memoramaList = MemoramaS.getAllMemoramaDB()
   return memoramaList

Este es mi archivo js donde la consumo:
fetch('https://dagcerqtrd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/devadmin-juegos/get-memoramas', 
 {
 // fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin-juegos/get-memoramas',{
      method: 'GET',
      headers:{
      "Content-Type":"application/json",
    'x-api-key': 'api-key',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
}
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    // Ocultar la alerta de carga
    Swal.close();

    const tableBody = document.querySelector('#myTable tbody');

    // Limpiar cualquier dato previo en la tabla (precaución para recargas dinámicas)
    tableBody.innerHTML = '';

    // Agregar datos obtenidos a la tabla
    data.forEach(item => {
        const row = `
            <tr>
                <td>${item.id_memorama}</td>
                <td>${item.title}</td>
                <td>
                    <img src="${item.image1}" class="img-fluid" width="100" alt="">
                    <img src="${item.image2}" class="img-fluid" width="100" alt="">
                    <img src="${item.image3}" class="img-fluid" width="100" alt="">
                    <img src="${item.image4}" class="img-fluid" width="100" alt="">
                    <img src="${item.image5}" class="img-fluid" width="100" alt="">
                    <img src="${item.image6}" class="img-fluid" width="100" alt="">
                    <img src="${item.image7}" class="img-fluid" width="100" alt="">
                    <img src="${item.image8}" class="img-fluid" width="100" alt="">
                </td>
                <td>${item.time} segundos</td>
                <td>
                    <a href="viewMemorama.html?id=${item.id_memorama}" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a>
                    <a href="editarMemorama.html?id=${item.id_memorama}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a>
                    <a onclick="return deleteMemorama('${item.id_memorama}')" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                    <a onclick="return copyUrl('${item.id_memorama}')" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="far fa-clone"></i></a>
                    
                </td>
            </tr>`;
        tableBody.innerHTML += row;
    });

    // Inicializar DataTables después de agregar los datos
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        destroy: true, // Permitir reinicialización si es necesario
        language: {
            url: 'https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.13.6/i18n/es-ES.json'
        },
    });
})
.catch(error => {
    // Muestra una alerta de error si algo sale mal
    Swal.fire({
        icon: 'error',
        title: 'Error',
        text: 'No se pudieron cargar los datos. Por favor, intenta de nuevo.',
    });
    console.error('Error:', error);
});

la forma en como cree mi recurso en aws fue habilitando la casilla CORS como se muestra en la imagen

asi es como estan mis metodos


Espero me puedan apoyar a ver mi error, se los agradecería mucho ya que no puedo encontrarlo.
